# Where does the index.html redirect to? [Moodle Mobile][Javascript]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

My current tasked with adding a QR code generation functionality to Moodle Mobile's source code to `add more functions`. 
 The source code that I use is from this [site](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile-phonegapbuild).

As I don't have any experience in Javascript (or AngularJS which is what Moodle is using), I'm quite confused when I am looking for a place to `add` the functions. 
So,I'm stuck on the first page when the app loads, which is the `index.html`

The current `index.html` looks like this below mentioned code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * filesystem: cdvfile: file: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; img-src * filesystem: gap: data: cdvfile: file: https://ssl.gstatic.com android-webview-video-poster:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' filesystem: cdvfile: file:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:* filesystem: cdvfile: file:">
    <title></title>
    <link href="build/mm.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ydn.db/jsc/ydn.db-dev.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-md5/angular-md5.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jszip/dist/jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ckeditor/angular-ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="build/mm.bundle.js"></script>
    <style></style> <!-- Empty style to make easier to test styles using Inspector. -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mm">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

From my perspective, the `index.html` should look empty on a browser as there is no `content` in the header and body anyway. 
 But when I open `index.html` in a web browser, it actually shows a proper page with a header `Connect to Moodle` and forms such as `Site address`.

An example of how it looks like is [here](http://prototype.moodle.net/mobile/webapp/#/mm_login/site)

So my question is, **where does the index.html link to**? Where do i find the source code for the site displayed on the web browser? I suspect the `index.html` links to something else as the URL shown on the web browser when I open this:

```
file:///C:/Users/teeti_000/Documents/GitHub/moodlemobile-phonegapbuild/index.html#/mm_login/site
```

I tried searching for `mm_login` in the related folders but can't find anything aside from other `.html` files that refer to mm_login and mm.bundle.js, mm.bundle.min.css and mm.bundle.css

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Best Regards.

Comment: Refer this [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile-phonegapbuild/master/build/mm.bundle.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile-phonegapbuild/master/build/mm.bundle.js) this file and search for what you are looking for. Here you have all the logics an mm-login too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your directory for "template" folders. Since angular is loading additional templates, which do the HTML Stuff.
moodlemobile-phonegapbuild/core/components/login/templates/site.html could be the correct one